# Data frame vector filtering using custom function

Tags: r, data-structures

I need to get a subset of my data frame based on the current row AND some calculations on the whole data frame column. I am trying to use R's vector notation to filter out the unwanted rows based on a custom function:

```
myDataFrame[customFn(myDataFrame$A, ????? <<here I need to reference not just the current value of myDataFrame$A, but the whole vector myDataFrame$A>> ),]
```

My customFn takes 2 arguments: a number and a vector, and it returns a vector of booleans. How do I pass in a whole column vector to the function? I don't want to use apply since I think it will be much slower than vector filtering

Thanks!

Comment: Passing the column `A` just as you have done will pass the full column... Please include some of the code you've tried including your `customFn` that you've written as well as a sample data set.

Comment: customFn is the gdist function in the package 'Imap'. My data frame consists of lat/longs. For each row, I need to find "close neighbors" within 1 mile.

Answer (score 3):

As @Justin points out - as long as `customFn` returns a vector of logicals the same length as your data frame, you'll be fine. For example

```
# Define a function to return a vector of logicals based on the mtcars$mpg
keepers <- function(d, lower=18, upper=20) {
  to_keep <- rep(TRUE, nrow(d))
  to_keep[(d$mpg < lower) | (d$mpg > upper)] <- FALSE
  to_keep # True if d$mpg is between upper and lower
}

mtcars[keepers(mtcars), ]
```